# SyntaxError at octopress image_tag plugin when generating blog

Tags: ruby, jekyll, octopress

I use [octopress](http://octopress.org) for my technical blog. I updated my octopress codes from official octopress repo, and I get an error like that when I run `rake generate`:

```
 |1.9.3-p194| home in ~/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com
± |source ✓| → rake generate
## Generating Site with Jekyll
directory source/stylesheets/ 
   create source/stylesheets/screen.css 
Configuration from /Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/_config.yml
/Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/category_generator.rb:109: warning: regexp has invalid interval
/Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/category_generator.rb:109: warning: regexp has `}' without escape
/Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/category_generator.rb:146: warning: regexp has invalid interval
/Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/category_generator.rb:146: warning: regexp has `}' without escape
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `require': /Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/image_tag.rb:27: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?<class>\S.*\s+)?(?<src>(?:https?:\/\/|\/|\S+\/)\S+)(?:\s+(?<width>\d+))?(?:\s+(?<height>\d+))?(?<title>\s+.+)?/ (SyntaxError)
/Users/muratcorlu/Documents/work/git/muratcorlu.github.com/plugins/image_tag.rb:29: undefined (?...) sequence: /(?:"|')(?<title>[^"']+)?(?:"|')\s+(?:"|')(?<alt>[^"']+)?(?:"|')/
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:76:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `each'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:75:in `setup'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/../lib/jekyll/site.rb:30:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:224:in `new'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/jekyll-0.11.2/bin/jekyll:224
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23:in `load'
    from /usr/bin/jekyll:23
```

What is the problem?

Comment: did you compare with this line? (missing 'i') https://github.com/imathis/octopress/blob/master/plugins/image_tag.rb#L27

Comment: Yes, they are exactly same. My code is at github also: https://github.com/muratcorlu/muratcorlu.github.com/blob/source/plugins/image_tag.rb#L27

Comment: So what happens when you revert the merge from the Octopress of tip?  Basically I'm asking, did this error occur before the merge?  or, were you writing a new post and the error started? I ask because I've encountered several errors with tip, and usually revert - waiting for a bug report or to merge again a month later.

Answer (score 1):

First I tried the RegEx in irb:

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> /(?:"|')(?<title>[^"']+)?(?:"|')\s+(?:"|')(?<alt>[^"']+)?(?:"|')/
=> /(?:"|')(?<title>[^"']+)?(?:"|')\s+(?:"|')(?<alt>[^"']+)?(?:"|')/
irb(main):002:0>
```

I got no error, but then I found out that my default ruby version on the server was 1.8.7.

I chose ruby-1.9.3-p551 from rvm and made it active.

I did the following:

```
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p551
bundle install
bundle exec rake generate
```

This resolved the error for me.